# Conversion of oracle timestamp to postgres timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

oracle timestamp example: `26-APR-17 09.40.13.243356000`

Hi i have a scenario I am converting oracle timestamp to postgres timestamp but the output is not expected .

Query run in psql

```
migration=# SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('26-APR-17 09.40.13.243356000','DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS:MS') :: timestamp without time zone;
        to_timestamp
----------------------------
   2017-04-26 09:15:55.864128                  ----- this is output 
(1 row)
```

The output should be: `2017-04-26 09:40:13.243356`

[image]

Comment: No database is going to arbitrarily add a half hour. This sounds like a timezone issue, if one of the two databases uses the Indian timezone. You didn't post the *actual* code though. The values you posted look like the *localized result* of some query, not actual values. Very few countries use such delimiters. Only India uses a half-hour offset (that I know of)

Comment: To avoid localization issues use the ISO8601 format, ie `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.ffffZ` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.ffff+HH:mm`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos look at the picture . I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that 243356000 is taken as milliseconds, which accounts for the strange offset of about half an hour.

Trim the last three sigits and use `US` for microseconds:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(
          regexp_replace(
             '26-APR-17 09.40.13.243356000',
             '\d{3}$',
             ''
          ),
          'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS.US'
       );
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is a result of the invalid value for the milliseconds format mask `MS`.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) the allowed values for milliseconds are from 000 to 999

`.243356000` is however also not valid for microseconds (`US` format mask) because of the trailing zeroes.

If you want to use that format, you have to remove the zeros from the input string, e.g: using `rtrim()`

```
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(rtrim('26-APR-17 09.40.13.243356000','0'),'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS.US');
         to_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2017-04-26 09:40:13.243356+02
(1 row)

postgres>
```

---

I also agree with PanagiotisKanavos that it would be better to use a locale independent format (i.e. numbers for the month and a 4 digit year), preferably an ISO standard for timestamp values.

Comment: That will lead to wrong results if the last three digits are not all 0.